# sqlite operationalerror even though code works for others

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I've been having trouble with the following sql query to compute the distances of a traveled path using the x,y coordinates of the mouse at any given time. The code does work for other people, but it keeps giving an error for me. When removing the lines for the diff_x and diff_y, the error is gone.

```
query_length = '''
    SELECT user, trial, t, x, y,
    x - LAG(x,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY user, trial, t) AS diff_x,
    y - LAG(y,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY user, trial, t) AS diff_y
    FROM paths;
'''

df_path_length = pd.read_sql_query(query_length, conn_experiment)
df_path_length.set_index(['user', 'trial'], inplace=True)
df_path_length
```

I keep getting the following error: https://pastebin.com/A6yXgapP (includes the same code at the top).

If anyone sees what I am missing and could lend me a hand I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That error is typical when you're trying to use window functions on an old version of sqlite that doesn't support them.

Comment: You should also include the error messages directly in your question, not in a link.